# Cooling 1.5 cu ft with a TEC1-12715 Peltier

Tags: thermal, peltier, cooling

I'm trying to modify a standard cooler (about 1.5 cu ft) so it no longer requires ice. I want to get the interior to 35 - 40F assuming the ambient temperature is about 75-80F. However, I don't have much experience with thermoelectric cooling. How suited would a TEC1-12715 Peltier be for this task and would I need more than one for this? I'm also trying to decide if water cooling the system or fan cooling it would be more efficient since electricity consumption is also a concern of mine. Ideally the system could keep the interior at a consistent temperature for 2 days.

Also would a TEC1-12706 work for this too or should I stick with the TEC1-12715?

Comment: You've left out an important fact: heat removal burden. How effective is the insulation of the enclosure? How much heat might leak into it though openings, wires or other breaks, **including the Peltier cooler itself**? How much heat is generated inside by any process, suc as electrical devices inside the enclosure? However, if you can provide external cooling, such as evaporating water, it's likely doable.

Comment: Ideally it would be pre-chilled drinks like cans of soda and some foods like cheese or uncooked hotdogs. The cooler its self would probably be a modified Coleman 40-Quart cooler the website claims that when its filled with ice it can maintain the temperature for 3 days, though I would want the system to function without ice.

Comment: It might be better to buy a complete Peltier food cooler, e.g. https://www.practical-sailor.com/belowdecks-amenities/galley/marincool-peltier-effect-refrigeration , that's undergone testing so you can plan on the maximum current and total power needs.

Comment: I would but this is a school project so I'm pretty sure outright buying Peltier food coolers like that is off the table

Comment: To your parts list, then, add an interior thermostat for ~35 °F, an *overheat* thermal switch for the hot (outside) of the Peltier cooler, and a fan to cool the hot side. It's small., so you might not need an internal circulator fan *if* there's enough insulation. A commercial device *similar* to what you're making uses about 50 watts when running, so you need to size the power supply accordingly. And yes, your idea should be OK.